# stratified sampling in pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, sampling, downsampling

Does anyone have an idea of how to make a stratified sampling in pig? 
([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling))

For the moment, I do something like :

```
relation2 = SAMPLE relation1 0.05;
```

but my dataset contains a label columns with a few occurrences, some of them are rare (0.5 % for example) and I would like my random down sampling not to forget all of them.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your own method of sampling by using `RANDOM()` and then filtering out rows with values below, say, 0.95.  So, if you want to stratify this sampling, you could compute what fraction of your rows contain a certain value, and then scale your random value accordingly so that different values get sampled at different rates.